# Проблемы с объектом Абстрактного Базового Класса

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, уважаемые дамы и господа!

У меня возникла некоторая несуразица с определением Абстрактного Базового Класса. В книге "Язык программирования С++. Лекции и Упражнения" господин Стивен Прата пишет:
"Если объявление класса содержит чисто виртуальную функцию, то объект такого класса создать невозможно.", - стр. 696.

Я написал Абстрактный Базовый Класс и в телах его конструктора и деструктора обозначил их вызов:

```
cout << "Destructor ABC;"<< endl;","cout << "Constructor ABC;" << endl;
```

Однако при вызове объекта "конкретного класса", несмотря на то, что (как пишет господин Прата) объект Абстрактного Базового Класса создать невозможно, у меня вместе с конструктором и деструктором "конкретного класса" почему-то вызываются конструктор и деструктор Абстрактного Базового Класса. Может быть, всё в порядке, и конструктор, и деструктор АБК только вызываются, но сам объект при этом не создаётся?

Все конструкторы я инициализировал при помощи "списка инициализаторов". Буду очень рад, если разрешите мои сомнения...

Answer (score 3):

Доброго времени суток!

Стивен Прата прав, возможно лишь, он не уточнил, что объект абстрактного класса нельзя создать напрямую, т.е. на стеке или через оператор new:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Абстрактный базовый класс
class AbstractBase
{
public:
   AbstractBase() {}
   virtual ~AbstractBase() {}
   virtual void show() = 0;
};

class Derived : public AbstractBase
{
public:
    Derived() {}
    ~Derived() {}
    void show() { cout << "I am Derived" << endl; }

};

int main()
{
    AbstractBase sbase; // ОШИБКА: нельзя создать объект абстрактного класса
    AbstractBase *pbase = new AbstractBase; // ОШИБКА: нельзя создать объект абстрактного класса

    Derived sd; // OK: создание класса наследника на стеке
    AbstractBase *d0 = new Derived; // OK: создание класса наследника с автоматическим приведением к базовому "в куче"
    Derived *d1 = new Derived; // создание класса наследника "в куче"

    sd.show();
    d0->show();
    d1->show();

    delete d0;
    delete d1;
    return 0;
}
```

Вопрос, почему нельзя создавать объект абстрактного базового класса - потому что он содержит *чисто виртуальные функции* **не имеющие реализации** (они предназначены для реализации в классах наследниках). Если бы можно было создавать объекты таких классов, то непонятно тогда,  как вызывать функции этих классов, не имеющие реализации?

Что касается коструктора(ов)/деструктора: это просто функции, да, это специальные функции - но это функции, и в целом их вызов ничему не противоречит.

Почему в классе наследнике вызывается конструктор базового класса (а точнее всех базовых в порядке наследования)? Поскольку при наследовании данные и функции базового класса как бы *добавляются* к данным и функциям класса наследника (ну, за исключением тех самых чисто виртуальных и виртуальных функций). Поэтому мы обязаны проинициализировать сначала поля базового класса, а затем наследника(ов). Если мы этого **не сделаем**, то при любом обращении к этим полям получим UB!

Вам следует обратить внимание вот на какие детали (про которые Прата, возможно, умолчал):

1. Порядок вызова конструкторов и деструкторов четко определен.
2. Вызов чисто виртуального метода в конструкторе абстрактного класса - это UB!
3. Отсутствие виртуального деструктора абстрактного базового класса приводит к тому, что этот деструктор никогда не будет вызываться (что в свою очередь может привести к утечке памяти).

Надеюсь, ответил на Ваш вопрос наиболее полно. Если есть вопросы - задавайте!

Успехов!

Comment: +1. Под «невозможно создать» в книге имелось в виду «невозможно создать объект именно в точности этого класса», про объекты производных классов ничего не говорилось. В процессе создания объекта производного класса вызывается и конструктор базового, абстрактного класса.